# connected component and path connected component

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

- What are the connected components and path connected components of $\Bbb{Q}$ , $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{l}$?

> Definition: A component $C$ of a topological space $X$ is a maximal connected subspace.

I think every connected component of $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{l}$ consists of just one point. Because, if we  take any subset say $S$ with at least two distinct points of $\Bbb{R}$ then $S$ can't be connected. If $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$ be two distinct points, such that $x<y$ then $A=(-\infty,x)\cap S$ and $B=(y,\infty)\cap S$ are disjoint non-empty open sets in the subspace topology on $S$.
Therefore, $S$ is disconnected.
If the above proof is true for $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{l}$.

Similar proof for path component.

Is this even true for $\Bbb{R}$? I mean $\Bbb{R}$ has components that consists of just one point.

I believe $\Bbb{Q}$ has also connected components that consists of just one point.

Any help or hint will be appreciable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about $\Bbb R_\ell$ and $\Bbb Q$. For instance, $\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\text{ and }a<b\}$ is a clopen base for $\Bbb Q$, so $\Bbb Q$ is totally disconnected (and even zero-dimensional). $\Bbb R$, however, is path-connected and hence also connected: for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$, the map

$$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto a+(b-a)x$$

is a path from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Then every closed and open interval of $\Bbb{R}$ is connected component as well as path component.

Comment: @AmanPandey: No, a (path) component is a **maximal** (path) connected set, and the only maximal (path) connected subset of $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$ itself. $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are connected and even path connected, but they are not components of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Any interval in $\Bbb{R}$ is component. Since path components partition components. We  can not partition intervals because they are connected. Hence the only path components of $\Bbb{R}$ is $\Bbb{R}$ itself. Am I right?

Comment: @AmanPandey: Your first statement is false. Did you mean that every interval in $\Bbb R$ is **connected**? That is true. $\Bbb R$ is path-connected because any two real numbers can be joined by a path, i.e., a continuous map from $[0,1]$ having the numbers in question as $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, as I proved in my answer.

Comment: @AmanPandey: You’re welcome!

Comment: I am a bit confuse. closed intervals of $\Bbb{R}$ is component. Right!

Comment: @AmanPandey: No, they are not. They are connected, but they are not components, because they are contained in bigger connected sets. For instance, $[0,1]$ is properly contained in the connected set $[0,2]$, so it is not a **maximal** connected set. In fact $\Bbb R$ itself is connected, and every connected subset of $\Bbb R$ is contained in $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R$ is the only maximal connected subset of $\Bbb R$, i.e., the only component of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thats' what I was thinking. A very great thanks to you Professor.

Comment: @AmanPandey: You’re very welcome.